# How would I Redirect an existing WooCommerce customer to a specific url after Checkout

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to find a solution for redirecting existing customers to a specific url after checkout. I'm not sure if the  Thank you page redirect is sufficient for the process. can you assist?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The following should suffice. It will redirect to your custom URL only if the order has not failed.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'ii_redirect_thankyou');
function ii_redirect_thankyou( $order_id ){
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => 2, // getting 2 as by the time this purchase has happened the count will be 1.
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed', // Only orders with "completed" status
        'fields'      => 'ids', // Return Ids "completed"
    ) );

    if ( count($customer_orders) > 1 ) {
      $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
      $url = 'http://example.com';

      // double check this order has gone through okay and then redirect them
      if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
      }
    }
}
```

function woocommerce_redirect_after_checkout(){
global $wp;
if (is_checkout()&&!empty($wp->query_vars['order-completed'])){
$redirect_url='https://example.com';
wp_redirect($rediect_url);
exit;
}
}

Comment: So can this statement identify is they are an existing customer? cause i only want it to work with customers whom have already purchased from me, Not new customers. Im making it now were all have to create accounts no guest purchases.

Comment: I've adjusted the code to do as you need though I've not actually tested it so tweaks may be required.

Comment: I added the code and tried to tweak it a bit, but its not going to the external link i want: this is what i did: